# No PostgreSQL link opened yet

Tags: php, database

I am completly new to databases and am trying to make a simple query to a postgreSQL database. Now the problem is that I don't really understand how things work. In my index.php I do

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=myhost port=5432 dbname=mydbname user=myuser password=mypass sslmode=require options='--client_encoding=UTF8'") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
```

And I am connected to the database. When I try to query it from another myphp.php

```
$query = "INSERT INTO public.account_recover_users VALUES ($mykey,$email,$name)";
$result = pg_query($query);
```

I get the error in the title description. What is the proper way to connect to the database so that I can access it from other files than index.php as well?

P.S. `$mykey,$email,$name` are 3 variables containing a key (randomly-generated), an email and a name.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php): "_Although connection can be omitted, it is not recommended, since it can be the cause of hard to find bugs in scripts._" Have you tried `pg_query($dbconn, $query)`?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I am connecting to database, but I am doing it in index.php. The question is what should I do to query from myphp.php. Do I need to write the pg_connect part in each of the php files?

Comment: Yes, assuming 'myphp.php' is not included by 'index.php', you need to open the connection in each script. You can do this cleanly by putting your connection details in a single file and use `include()` to access it in each script that needs it.

Comment: LOL right. Didn't think about including it. I am a starter in web development in general and i'm not yet aware of all features. Thanks

Comment: could you include this as an answer?  I would be happy to upvote.